# tools for testing ssh packets size

Tags: openssh

I need to test maximum-packet-size for SSH protocol. Would be grateful for information on possible tools that can be used for this. What I specifically need is the possibility to indicate packet length and to insure that data was send as one packet.

Comment: this is more of a networking question than a security question - I assume you are familiar with Wireshark?